# Cloudinary Image Upload Using PHP Not Working

Tags: php, cloudinary

I used cloudinary for image upload, I tried all possible ways to upload the image but my code stuck at..

```
$cloudUpload = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']);
```

Here is my code,

```
<?php
require 'Cloudinary.php';
require 'Uploader.php';

\Cloudinary::config(array(
    "cloud_name" => "xxxxx",
    "api_key" => "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "api_secret" => "_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
));

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    print_r($_FILES["fileToUpload"]);
    $cloudUpload = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']);
    print_r($cloudUpload);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
  </head>

  <body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Am not getting any response at all from cloudinary and no errors on require line on top.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works great on my end.
Make sure everything is ok with your credentials and your Cloudinary account.
If this problem persists, for further and more account-specific assistance, you should [open a support-ticket](http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) with Cloudinary.

Answer (score 0):

*for any stumbling on this question, also check your php version. 
Cloudinary PHP SDK requires php 5.4.*

[image]